# Google Extension Edit Address Bar Content

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have built a Chrome extension that edits the new tab page by replacing it with the `index.html` of my site. The only problem is that the address bar shows `https://example.com/index.html/`. How can I make the address bar blank, or edit it to something like `Search here`?

I tried to edit my site's code such that on page load, the text is edited, but it changes to `https://example.com/search-here.html/`.

Is there any Chrome extensions permission/property I can use, or some other thing I can do on the server end?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to register an override page in the extension manifest.

Override pages are a way to substitute an HTML file from your extension for a page that Google Chrome normally provides. In addition to HTML, an override page usually has CSS and JavaScript code.

Here’s an example from the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/override/):

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...

  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "pageToOverride": "myPage.html"
  },
  ...
}
```

For *pageToOverride*, substitute one of the following:

- bookmarks
- history
- newtab

Comment: Thanks a ton :) I'll try this out tomorrow. Would you know what will be displayed in the address bar if I override `newtab` with my page?

Comment: It will be empty and already have focus.

Comment: I understand. Thanks again:)